# Unknown error when trying to find the only odd or even number in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on a code wars questions: 
You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The integers in the array are either entirely odd or entirely even except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns N.

For example:

[2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]

Should return: 11

[160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]

Should return: 160

The compiler doesn't show an error, but when I run this code I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
    snippet.evensAndOdds.find(evensAndOdds.java:21) at 
    snippet.evensAndOdds.main(evensAndOdds.java:13)
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the code. Can anyone explain?

I have to run it against these test cases:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

public class OutlierTest{
@Test
public void testExample() {
     int[] exampleTest1 = {2,6,8,-10,3}; 
     int[] exampleTest2 =            {206847684,1056521,7,17,1901,21104421,7,1,35521,1,7781}; 
 int[] exampleTest3 = {Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, 1};
 assertEquals(3, FindOutlier.find(exampleTest1));
 assertEquals(206847684, FindOutlier.find(exampleTest2));
 assertEquals(0, FindOutlier.find(exampleTest3));
```

}}

```
static int find(int[] integers){

    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++)
        if (integers [i] % 2 == 0){
            evens.add(integers[i]);
            } else if (integers [i] % 2 != 0){
                odds.add(integers[i]);
            } else if (integers.length == 1){
                send = integers[i];
            }

                if (evens.size() > odds.size()){
                    send = odds.get(0);
                } else {
                    send = evens.get(0);
                }
                  return send;
                }
}
```

Comment: `but when I run this code I get an error.` What error? Please [edit] your question to include the error you're seeing.

Comment: The error is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at snippet.evensAndOdds.find(evensAndOdds.java:21)
 at snippet.evensAndOdds.main(evensAndOdds.java:13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your problem is at the declaration of your `evens` and `odds` list.

When you call `evens.add(integers[i]);`, evens itself is not declared. The piece is missing in your snippet, but I'm guessing you have the following:

```
List<Integer> evens;
```

Instantiating it before calling a method will resolve the `NullPointerException`. You can't call methods on objects that were never instantiated.

```
List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked in my compiler, but it failed to work on code wars for some reason. I have some test cases. Is there any reason this wouldn't work with these? I have put them in my original question.

Comment: @SimonAugustus Well I don't really know what the demands of Code Wars are. There could be dozens of ways to implement what you seek. Your error is fixed however and you get the desired result. So there isn't much more I'm able to answer.

Comment: Thanks Jaims, voted your answer. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @SimonAugustus No problem. Normally on StackOverflow you can select a certain asnwer as "solution". It's below the up and down vote buttons. The up and down vote are to say if it's useful, but not necessary the solution.